# ObjectId to identify a UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I have a simple pill reminder app and I'm storing a small amount of data in NSUserDefaults. When a user edits or deletes a reminder, the respective UILocalNotification needs to be modified. Using the `userInfo` dictionary of the UILocalNotitification, I've made the key `@"reminderId"` to edit/delete the respective reminder.

When a reminder is first created, I set the `@"reminderId"` to the initial `@"name"` a user gives the reminder. So if the user initially sets the `@"name"` to "Daily Vitamin" and later changes the `name` to "Multi-Vitamin", "Daily Vitamin" will persist as the `@"reminderId`.

Is this a safe practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not safe, because after the customer renames Daily Vitamin to Multi-Vitamin, he might create a new reminder for a different pill and call it Daily Vitamin. Now there's a conflict. It'd probably be easier to create an auto-incrementing numeric key, then you don't have to worry about names and such. Each pill reminder that gets created has key = key + 1, regardless.

Keep track of the current key with your UserDefaults and that will be that. =)